# Add a Panoramio-like layer to ArcGIS Online map

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, photos, integration, panorama

I am interested in integrating some type of Panoramio-like layer into a map on ArcGIS.com.  My objective is to be able to use the qualitative, place-based data offered by the photos with students who routinely use ArcGIS Online.  It appears that Panoramio will no longer be available.  Is there an alternative and can it be added to AGOL?

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ sends requests back in REST,XML-RPC,SOAP,JSON,PHP which ArcGIS Online can consume.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use the qualitative, place-based data offered by the photos" that was available through Panoramio?

Comment: To elaborate: The photos can be used in conjunction with quantitative data to aid in the understanding of place.  For example, percentage of people who practice subsistence agriculture could be quantitative data while the actual photo of someone working on their plot provides the context associated with qualitative data.  For 15 year olds who have never really traveled outside of the U.S. this can be quite helpful and engaging.

Comment: Thank you Mapperz.  What is the general method for incorporating flickr into ArcGIS Online?  I am not interested in adding my own photos.  Rather, I would like to add the publicly available photos to the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides a transition to their other products which maintain the same placed-based data as Panoramio provided [here](http://www.panoramio.com/maps-faq).

> Today, with photo upload tools in Google Maps and our Local Guides program, we are providing easy ways for you to share your photos with an active and growing community. As such, we’ve decided to move forward with closing down Panoramio. To make this transition easier, we’ll provide several options to continue sharing photos through other services. If you choose, you can also export all your data and take it somewhere else.

Additionally, I came across this Esri [map template](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f01baaccb4b84bcbb9ac0810e717cae3) which provides you with the ability to:

> Present a map with geolocated content from Twitter, Instagram, Flickr, YouTube and webcams.travel. Optionally allows users to swipe between layers and print maps.

[image]

It also provide the following configurable options

> Configurable Options
>   Public Information present content from a web map with social media feeds and can be configured using the following options:
>
> Provide a title and description, as well as configure a custom splash screen that displays when the app is first loaded.
>
> Set up an interactive layer for taking notes. This is a map notes layer contained in the web map.
>
> Enable a swipe layer and choose between vertical or horizontal orientation.
>
> Determine a default and alternate basemap to be offered in an on screen basemap widget.
>
> Enable layers to be generated via content from Instagram, Flickr, Twitter, Webcams.travel, and YouTube.
>
> Configure the ability for feature and location search.
>
> Enable or disable many UI and mapping configurable options such as overview map, bookmarks, share dialog, legend, summary information, views count, modified date, etc.

[image]